what could be causing hiding of columns after rendwering once in ag grid
I am using ag grid which has a side text
This side bar contains 'columns' tab , on clicking of column name we can hide/unhide columns from ui
So the issue I am facing is even tho I am providing hide:false in gridOptions config
my columns are de-selected from this columns sidepanel after rendering once.
the columns appears for 1-2 seconds and then dissapears. When I opened the 'columns' panel I saw that the columns were de-selcted, Is there any API calling internally that Im not aware of ?
What can be causing this issue?

